# Can a 4GE SSM accept Twinax connections if the speed is set to 1000 on the switch?

Tags: cisco, sfp

I have a Nexus 5548UP and an ASA 5510 with the 4GE SSM.  The 4GE has SFP ports and I would like to use them and conserve my Gigabit SFP transceivers for other uses.

The Twinax will insert into the ASA 5510, but I don't get any indication from the IOS that it is working.  The interface is down and shows no transceiver.

Is Twinax compatible with plain SFP ports?

Can a 4GE SSM accept Twinax connections if the speed is set to 1000 on the switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100 % sure, but I had the general impression that only SFP+ supports twinax. The SFP modules on a 4GE module is SFP (not SFP+).

Comment: Thank you @pauska :)  That confirms my suspicions here.  Twinax is SFP+ and the port is SFP.  It might work the other way around, but SFP+ certainly won't work in an SFP port.